# Upload image to server - Hapi.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, hapi.js, flux

I'm trying to upload an image to my server, and then save it to MongoDB. I'm using Hapi.js, React.js, Flux and Mongoose.

What I get in the payload is the following. Is this the path to the image?

```
{ path: '/var/folders/rl/6ygb2kgx7xnbkhnrpdxlbcl80000gp/T/1430991015360-27136-94254437ff20c8ce',
  bytes: 68 }
```

Sorry if this question is a bit long, but I wanted to include all the steps.

Here is the form:

```
<form method="POST"  onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <input type="file" name="newImage" ref="image" accept="image/*" />
    <input type="submit" value="Share image" />
</form>
```

Here is the handleSubmit:

```
handleSubmit: function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var image = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.image).value;
    var data = {
        image: image
    };
    ActionCreators.saveImage(data);
    },
```

Then, ActionCreators passes it on to APIUtils:

```
saveImage: function(data){
    APIUtils.saveImage(data);
}
```

Finally, APIUtils sends the image as an AJAX request to the server:

```
saveImage: function(data){
    Request.post('/api/image')
        .send(data)
        .end(function(err,res){
            // do something with the response later on
        });
}
```

Now, I'm trying to get access to this image on the server. Server.js:

```
{
    path: '/api/image',
    method: ['POST'],
    config: {
         payload: {
           output:'file',
           maxBytes:209715200,
           parse: false
        },

        auth: {
            strategy: 'session',
            mode: 'try'
        },
        handler: function(request,reply){
            var payload = request.payload;
            console.log('payload: ', payload);
        },
        plugins: {
            'hapi-auth-cookie': {
                reddirectTo: '/'
            }
        }
```

Comment: Nope... You can send the image as buffer.

Comment: An alternative would be to send the image in a base64 format as a string. Since you are planning on saving it on mongodb, this would simplify both the upload and storage of the images.